# postgres on docker fails with `chown: cannot dereference ... : No such file or directory`

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to deploy `postgres` on docker and it exits immediately after I run it. On checking the logs I get the following error:

```
chown: cannot dereference '/var/lib/postgresql/data/venv/bin/python3': No such file or directory
```

The command am running is here below:

```
sudo docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=superset -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypostgrespassword -e POSTGRES_DB=superset --volume $PWD:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure you want to mount `$PWD` to that place? This is dependent on the directory you are currently in. I'd suggest to create a new, empty directory (e.g. `/opt/pgdata`) and mount that one: `--volume /opt/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data` The cause of your error is probably that the directory you are mounting is not empty.

Comment: Working perfectly after creating empty directory. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that the directory you are mounting, is not empty.
Create a empty directory, for example `/opt/pgdata` and then mount that one:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=superset -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypostgrespassword -e POSTGRES_DB=superset -v /opt/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```